Help on Prove by induction, $n=a+1$ case simplification
I've been stuck on this question for a bit, I am unsure of how to factorize factorial and is stuck at this stage. If someone can give me a hint on where to go next, it would be highly appreciated!
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2k - 1) = \frac{(2n)!}{n! 2^n} \quad (n \geq 1).$$
Where I got to
$\prod_{k=1}^{a+1} (2k-1)$
$= (\prod_{k=1}^{a} (2k-1))(2(a+1)-1)$
$= \frac{(2a)!}{a!2^a}(2a+1)$
$= \frac{(2a)!(2a+1)}{a!2^a}$

Good, then multiply both the denominator and numerator by something that makes the denominator $(a+1)!2^{a+1}$.

$$= \frac{(2a)!(2a+1)}{a!2^a}$$
$$=\frac{2a+2}{2(a+1)}×\frac{(2a)!(2a+1)}{a!2^a}$$
$$=\frac{(2a+2)!}{(a+1)!2^{a+1}}$$

Ahhh thank you, I have no idea why I didn't think about that changing the denominator at all.

@KittySummoner you forgot the little thing that 2(a+1)=2a+2. Anyways have a great day
